# jq: Using nested field name as a command-line argument for group_by statement

Tags: command-line, jq

I'm building a generic group-by JQ script (as detailed [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52497587/jq-count-number-of-objects-per-group-for-a-subset-of-input)) which accepts a field to be grouped as a command-line argument.

It works fine when I group by top-level field; it doesn't when I need to group by a field deep in an hierarchy of objects:

jq_group_on_test.json:

```
{
    "a": {
      "b": {
        "c": "EFG"
      }
    },
    "d": "HIJ"
  }
```

Top-level field:

```
jq -s --arg group_by_field "d" '
  group_by(.[$group_by_field])
  | .[]
  | [ (.[0][$group_by_field] ) ]' \
jq_group_on_test.json 

[
  "HIJ"
]
```

Field from the nested object:

```
jq -s --arg group_by_field "a.b.c" '
  group_by(.[$group_by_field])
  | .[]
  | [ (.[0][$group_by_field] ) ]' \
jq_group_on_test.json

[
  null
]
```

Same filter works if no variables used:

```
jq -s '
  group_by(.a.b.c)
  | .[]
  | [ (.[0].a.b.c ) ]' \
jq_group_on_test.json

[
  "DEF"
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass in a path as a parameter, you have to use the array-path notation (i.e., an array of strings and/or integers):

```
jq -s --argjson group_by_field '["a","b","c"]' '
  group_by( getpath($group_by_field) )
  | .[]
  | [ .[0] | getpath($group_by_field)  ]
' jq_group_on_test.json
```

Note the use of the command-line option `--argjson`.